# Graph where distance from first to last vertex is number of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I have a graph where the distance from the first vertex to the last vertex is equal to the number of vertices minus 1.

Essentially, I'm picturing a graph where $1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4$ and the distance from $1$ to $4$ is $3$.

Is there a formal name for this graph?

Comment: A line graph or path.

Comment: @Kaind I would avoid "line graph" since that has a different, more common meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **path graph** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph), [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathGraph.html)). Wikipedia also calls it a *linear graph* but I see that much less frequently.

It is denoted $P_n$, where $n$ is *usually* the number of vertices, but occasionally you see $P_n$ for the path graph with $n$ edges, instead.